# referencing and dereferencing files from xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I am working on a project in which some of the files are not referenced from project but they are used inside of other classes. It is not throwing file not found error.

for example **myclass** is a file which is not added into project (It is not available in project navigator) but it is imported in some other class like **#import "myclass.h"**. If I do jump to definition It is opening that myclass file in xcode editor. there is no path is shown.

Can any one know how they included those files in to project?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will find files that are in any of the search paths passed to it. When you compile your project, Xcode will output the command that it runs to the log and you can look at the arguments it sent to the compiler.

To see this, click on the Build Log button in the navigator and select your last build. In the build log window, click on the "All Messages" tab to see every step of the build, even the successful ones. On the right side of the message pane, there's an invisible button. If you select one line, it will show up. Or if you hover over it, it will appear and it looks like a tiny page with text. Click on it to see all the arguments that Xcode sends to the compiler. It will look something like this:

> CompileC /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname-oaenustheonoresuorcoehun/Build/Intermediates/projectanme.build/Debug/projectname.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o projectname/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd /Users/username/Development/projectname
>       export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 ... a bunch of deleted stuff ... -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk ... -I/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname-bdvjbpksruxnxobesveirmfeqgyn/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include ... -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname-bdvjbpksruxnxobesveirmfeqgyn/Build/Products/Debug ... -c /Users/username/Development/projectname/projectname/AppDelegate.m -o /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname-bdvjbpksruxnxobesveirmfeqgyn/Build/Intermediates/projectname.build/Debug/projectname.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o

The various `-I` and `-F` arguments tells clang (the compiler) where to look for files. There may also be implied directories, such as the directory the file you're compiling came from.

You can add your own paths for where the compiler should search for source files and headers. To do that, open the project navigator and click on your project's icon. This will open up the project settings editor. Click on the target you're working with (or the project if you want all targets to inherit the setting). Then click on the "Settings" tab. It should look something like this:

[image: Build settings]

If you enter "Search" in the search field, it will show the "Search Paths" settings. You can enter header, framework or library search paths there.

Comment: Thanks, then how can I use those files without adding into project?.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a picture that shows how to add your own search paths.